# How to update an attribute with spring CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

How can I create `update` methods in spring `CurdRepository`?

Something like:

```
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<PersonEntity> {
   //update ... set age =: age where name =: name
   boolean setAgeByName(age, name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ask me: do not use such queries. That's because your second level cache gets eradicated and you get some performance problems (your application will be slightly slower).

And by the way the process you want to do is in reality the following:

- you load your entity from the database
- change the attribute on the loaded object (via a setter method)
- you save your entity to the database (this is done automagically when your transaction ends so you do not need to call `PartnerRepository.save(entity)` explicitly)

If you want to use a query then I suggest you write your query as you mentioned in your question:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Person p set p.age = :age where p.name = :name")
int setAgeByName(@Param("age") int age, @Param("name") String name);
```

And you get back how many entries have been modified.

Comment: What if I have to set a single attribute on a large set of entries? I then would have to fetch the full entities and set the property within the transaction. But I want to avoid the fetch of all the data.